# Is there a counterexample to the claim that if $\mathbf y\cdot\mathbf y=1$ and $\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf y=c$ then $\mathbf x=c\mathbf y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $x,y$ be arbitrary vectors where $\mathbf{y} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 1$ and $c$ be a real valued scalar. If

$\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = c = c (\mathbf{y} \cdot \mathbf{y} ) = (c \mathbf{y} ) \cdot \mathbf{y} $, then

$\mathbf{x} = c \mathbf{y}$

Is this true? Feels like a sloppy conclusion no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we have counterexamples, let's look where the fault in the reasoning is.

When you say $x \cdot y = c y \cdot y$, you can't "eliminate" the common $y$ because that would require invertibility of the dot product.  By itself, the dot product is *not* invertible, and you cannot reconstruct $x$ without additional information:  in particular, information from the cross product.

Given a vector $x$, and a unit vector $y$, you can decompose $x$ as

$$x = (x \cdot y) y + y \times (x \times y) = x_\parallel + x_\perp$$

With the information you have, you know that $x_\parallel = cy$, but you don't know $x \times y$, and because of that, you don't know $x_\perp$.  If you *knew* that $x \times y =0$, then $x = x_\parallel$, and you'd know you're done.

Comment: So in Algebra sense, the vector space with the operation of dot product does not form a group?

Comment: Yes, that's true, in part because the dot product takes two elements of $\mathbb R^n$ and returns an element of $\mathbb R$, concerns of invertibilty aside.

Comment: Oh so closure failed from the start

Answer (score 8):

$\mathbf{x} = c \mathbf{y} + $ some vector perpendicular to $\mathbf{y}$

Comment: So if $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are not orthogonal, then it is okay?

Comment: @sizz: If $\rm x=y+z$ where $\rm z,y$ are orthogonal, then $\rm x,y$ are **not** orthogonal.

Comment: Are there circumstances in which my result could be true? Under what conditions?

Comment: @sizz: Your result is true under the condition that $\mathbf x$ is a multiple of $\mathbf y$. It really doesn't get any simpler than that.

Comment: Does it have to be a *linear* (constant) multiple?

Comment: @sizz:  Once you require that $\mathbf{x}$ is parallel with $\mathbf{y}$ the result follows.  The dot product ignores any component perpendicular.

Comment: So I guess that's your way of saying it doesn't have to be a constant multiple...?

Answer (score 6):

$x=(17,1)$, $y=(0,1)$. ${}{}{}{}$